# Switching dynamo DB tables before saving

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have following dynamodb table:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "customers")
public class Customer {
  private String id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  
  @DynamoDBHashKey
  @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
  public String getId() {...}
  public void setId(String id) {...}
  
  @DynamoDBAttribute
  public String getFirstName() {..}
  
  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {...} 
  
  @DynamoDBAttribute
  public String getLastName() {...}
  
  public void setLastName(String lastName) {...}
}
```

and I am saving this data using the below approach:

```
void saveData(DynamoDbMapper mapper, Customer c) {

     mapper.save(c);

}
```

This works fine and the data is saved to table **customers**. Now I have another table **customers_copy** in which I want to save this data instead of this table based on the customer name, how do I achieve this without using DynamoDBMapperConfig table resolver or without using table name override in dynamodbmapper ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, you must override the table name to change it, as you define the table name at client initiation.

The alternative is to use a low level client where you provide the table name in your input parameters.